# iPod doesn't mount correctly

Tags: mount, rhythmbox, ipod

I'm trying to sync rhythmbox to an iPod classic using Ubuntu 12.04. It worked at first, and then I got some error messages involving libgpod-common, and now the iPod doesn't even mount.  It doesn't show up in my file system, but I can see it in the disk utility, mounted at /tmp/ipodiA0gIP. When I try to safely remove it from the disk utility, it says that it's busy and can't be removed, but it works if I unmount it and then remove it from the disk utility.  How can I get it to pop up in Rhythmbox?

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer - this section is for your question.  Once done, you will be able to accept your own answer and we'll also be able to upvote you if your answer is well written.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. I got it to pop up in Rhythmbox by unmounting and remounting from the disk utility, but when I clicked on it Rhythmbox crashed. I tried to copy all the data from it before messing around any more, and found out that my album art files were damaged. I tried to delete them, but it was mounted read only. I installed hfsplus 
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hfsplus` which allowed me to modify the permissions so that I could delete the messed up artwork and other unneeded files, and now rhythmbox is re-initializing my ipod and it works.